# current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) does not work for contributer but for administrator

Tags: capabilities

I have a custom post type named `project` which has

```
'capability_type' => 'post'
```

while registering using `register_post_type`.

In my theme files and also `functions.php` file, I have situations where I should check if the project to be edited is authored by the user or not.

So I use this:

```
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $porject_id ) ) return;
```

where `$project_id` is post id of the project to be edited.

For example I have a page template named `single_project.php` where I can show single posts in project post type to users and I want these people can see each project single page:

1. administrators
2. editors
3. the contributor (post author)

but using the above code, It is ok with administrators and editors, while not for the contributor himself!

When I use:

```php
var_dump( current_user_can( 'edit_post', $project_id ) );
```

with the contributor logged-in account, it returns `false`, while this:

```php
var_dump( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ); // (with trailing 's')
```

returns `true` (but for every post, not just does for him).

Any help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using `map_meta_cap` I added `edit_post` per post cap to user

```
function my_map_meta_cap( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ){
    if ( 'edit_post' == $cap ) {
        $post = get_post( $args[0] );
        $post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );
        $caps = array();
        if ( $user_id == $post->post_author )
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->edit_posts;
        else
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->edit_others_posts;
    }
    return $caps;
}
add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'my_map_meta_cap', 10, 4 );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very late answer, but the accepted answer is incorrect, and I've seen other users referring to it, so I'm submitting the correct answer.

The reason the Contributor user was seeing `false` for `edit_post` is that Contributors cannot edit posts that have already been published. Only roles with `edit_published_posts` can do that.

In the original question, the author says:

> I have situations where I should check if the project to be edited is authored by the user or not.

That is *not* the same as whether or not a user can edit a post, which is what their code is actually checking. If you want to check whether the author of a post is a particular user, then that's what should be compared:

```
if ( get_current_user_id() === get_post_field( 'post_author', $project_id ) ) {
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: probably change === to ==, first one returns an integer while second one a string

Comment: @NabeelKhan, if that's the case, it probably would be better to typecast the second operand to an integer by prepending it with `(int)`