# Why does current_user_can('edit_posts') return true, but current_user_can('edit_post', $post->ID) returns false?

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles

I have a plugin with a custom post type (with `'capability_type' => 'post'`) and a custom user role (*test_user*). When I check if a user is allowed to edit a post (of the CPT and which this user created) with `current_user_can`, I get different results when using `edit_post` and `edit_posts` (with the **s**).

See example code below:

```php
register_post_type('test_cpt', [
        'labels'             => ['name' => 'TEST CPT'],
        'description'        => 'A custom post type for testing',
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => ['slug' => 'testcpt'],
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
]);

$new_post = [
    'post_content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.',
    'post_name' => 'test',
    'post_title' => 'TEST',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'test_cpt'
];
wp_insert_post($new_post);
$new_post = [
    'post_content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.',
    'post_name' => 'test_post',
    'post_title' => 'TEST post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'post'
];
wp_insert_post($new_post);

$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$data = get_userdata( $user_id );
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $data->allcaps, true ) . '</pre>';

$id = 153;
$post = get_post( $id ); 
echo '<dl>';

echo '<dt>current user: </dt>';
echo '<dd>'. $user_id . '</dd>';

echo '<dt>post id: </dt>';
echo '<dd>'. $post->ID . '</dd>';

echo '<dt>post_author: </dt>';
echo '<dd>'. $post->post_author . '</dd>';

echo '<dt>edit_posts: </dt>';
echo '<dd>'. (current_user_can('edit_posts') ? 'true' : 'false') . '</dd>';

echo '<dt>edit_post '.$post->ID.': </dt>';
echo '<dd>'. (current_user_can('edit_post', $post->ID) ? 'true' : 'false') . '</dd>';

echo '</dl>';
```

which results to:

```php
Array
(
    [read] => 1
    [edit_posts] => 1
    [upload_files] => 1
    [test_user] => 1
)

current user:     3
post id:          153
post_author:      3
edit_posts:       true
edit_post 153:    false
```

According to this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/126129/162474), `edit_post` *"evaluates to the capability edit_posts if the post_author field of this post matches the current users ID"*. Which makes sense and is what I expected it should do.

If I include the code provided in this [WP SE answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/193106/162474), then I also get true for `edit_post`.

But I do not understand why this is necessary. It seems to me, that there should be a better way to deal with this situation. I would image this is a pretty common use case.

Comment: I'm looking at the official docs and can find no evidence to support that `edit_post` exists https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/, although it appears in the WP codebase, but since it's a meta capability it will never appear in lists of capabilities. Also that user does not have many capabilities for that role

Comment: Can you update the code in your question to include code to recreate a minimal test case? The registration of the CPT and the user role in particular? Does this only happen with your custom role? Is the hardcoded post a `post` or the mystery post type?

Comment: `edit_post` is the second example in the description for `current_user_can` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/ and also mentioned in the comments on that page.

Comment: This answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/126129/162474 also mentions the functionality, and refers to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/map_meta_cap/ (I don't quite understand what the code is doing in regard to the post_type)

Comment: The behavior is the same for me, whether the post is of the type *post* or *mystery post type* (i.e. test_cpt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post in question is published, but your user is missing the `edit_published_posts` capability, so they're not allowed to edit it.